# <UL> Centered within a Div

Tags: css, list, xhtml, center

On a design I am coding, there is a horizontal list that serves as the navigation for the site. It spans the entire width of the page.
You can see it here:
http://aquate.us/film/

Now, the `<ul>` contained within `div#navigation` refuses to act centered within the div. It seems to be offset towards the left side.

I've searched the net and nothing I try works. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form, having the id of "search" is too tall.